# How to iterate through sequential string values and append to a nested list

Tags: python, string, list, append, nested-lists

I have a list containing filenames of a dataset, in the form of a number followed by some descriptive text (which is different for each file):

```
a = ['001_sometext', '002_sometext', ..., '162_sometext', '001_sometext', ..., '162_sometext]
```

The list cycles from `'001'` to `'162'` multiple times, but the list also doesn't follow a perfect sequence, some numbers are missing.

My intention is to read all files containing `'001'` and append them to another list, and then do the same for `'002'` and so on, such that I end up with a nested list containing a separate list for each number in the sequence.

My current attempt:

```
phrases = []
xi = []
for digits in range(0, 162):
    for x in a:
        if str(digits) in x:
            xi.append(x)
    phrases.append(xi)
```

However, this gives me a nested list of the entire list over and over again, rather than a list for each number.

Edit:

The loop above is reading all files containing just a `'0'`, which brings back hundreds of files and adds them to a list. A minor fix is that I've made a loop for each order of magnitude:

```
phrases = []
for digits in range(1, 10):
    xi = []
    for x in a:
        if '00' + str(digits) in x:
            xi.append(x)
        else: None
    phrases.append(xi)
```

and

```
phrases = []
for digits in range(10, 100):
    xi = []
    for x in a:
        if '0' + str(digits) in x:
            xi.append(x)
        else: None
    phrases.append(xi)
```

and

```
phrases = []
for digits in range(100, 162):
    xi = []
    for x in a:
        if str(digits) in x:
            xi.append(x)
        else: None
    phrases.append(xi)
```

Comment: Your loops could be correct if you clear the content of `xi` between iteration of the digits loop.

Comment: @TitouanL I've shifted the xi = [] so it's now within the digits for loop, which does work to a certain extent in the latter numbers. The main issue I think is that the loop iterates through '0' and adds to a list, which adds every file with a '0'. I've rectified this slightly which I'll explain in an edit.

Comment: Yes, I prepared an answer using `x.startswith(str(digits).rjust(3, '0'))`, but in the end @Nick's answer with the `f-string` works the same so I figured you could use his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code, firstly you need to clear `xi` on each loop; then you need to iterate in the range 1 to 163 (i.e. 1 to 162 inclusive) and finally you can't use `str(digits) in x` because (for example) `str(1)` would match against `001`, `015`, `102` etc.

Something like this should work:

```
for digits in range(1, 163):
    xi = []
    srch = f'{digits:03d}'
    for x in a:
        if x.startswith(srch):
            xi.append(x)
    phrases.append(xi)
```

Alternatively you could use a nested list comprehension:

```
phrases = [ [f for f in a if f.startswith(f'{n:03d}')] for n in range(1, 163)]
```

If

```
a = ['001_sometext', '002_sometext', '162_sometext', '001_someothertext', '162_someothertext']
```

both of these give a result of:

```
[['001_sometext', '001_someothertext'], ['002_sometext'], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], ['162_sometext', '162_someothertext']]
```